# Shiny R app error "too long to respond" but works from different directory

Tags: r, shiny

My organization runs Shiny apps over a server that pulls the app.R files from a directory. When I go to the internal site for the directory I get an error: "An error has occurred The application failed to start.  The application took too long to respond."

Runs local, and copy/paste from new folder in different directory as well too. Unfortunately cannot provide reproducible example sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with shiny in this case.

- You should check with your company. They may have some identification
  problem or an identity management software that is blocking the access from your shiny app. This is why your shiny app waits so long to have access to the directory but fails at the end.

In your place, I would check if there are any security barriers made
   by the company to secure their files. I am quite sure this is the
   problem and you have to request or ask for permissions to have access from shiny to that directory.

> --------- UPDATES for comments ---------

1. If you tried the same exact app with another directory and it worked well, **then it's definitely a problem with the directory and not shiny**. Most probably it should be with access permissions monitored by the IS admin. So yes, your understanding is correct!
2. In order to avoid any problem in the future, **keep everything as much as possible inside UI and server and avoid outside processing if you can**. It's a bad practice IMHO.

Comment: Thank you for responding! So to see if I understand correctly: if the exact same R shiny script produces a working app from one directory but times out in another directory, it is most likely an issue with the permissions?

Comment: If you tried the same exact app with another directory and it worked well, then it's definitely a problem with the directory and not shiny. Most probably it should be with access permissions monitored by the IS admin. So yes, your understanding is correct!

Comment: By the way, this happened to me once in a company!

Comment: Made a change to the app—it pulled a large amount of data. Before we had it pull the data before the Ui and Server were initialized. We changed it so the data was pulled reactive inside the server function. Allowed the app to initialize quicker even though the data was  still pulling. Does that sound like it would make sense or were we just lucky?

Comment: Ahuh! then you weren't running your code with the usual way. How come your data is pulled before initializing the UI or the server? you've had something outside the UI and server blocks? It's hard for me to tell in this case. 
That's why it's good to provide a reproducible example of your code!

Comment: Yes, exactly. The code to pull the data was outside the UI and server “function” so it would create a named object outside the Ui and server that would then be referenced and manipulated inside. As you may tell, I am quite new to shiny. Is it better practice to pull the data inside the server function?

Comment: I have done that too. We all have been there sometimes. I remember that I have the same exact thing and I decided to never do anything outside UI or server. My recommendation is, in order to avoid any problem in the future, keep everything as much as possible inside and avoid outside processing if you can. It's a bad practice IMHO.

Comment: Updates added in the answer